# Two regular loops with using given values for a parameter in MATLAB

Tags: string, algorithm, matlab, matrix

I have an `S1` (21x21) matrix and a `W` (21x21) matrix given. I define a matrix results with each element as a matrix as `results = {W};` 
and then, I have two regular for loops such that it runs all the values in index1 and then goes to the second index; but each time it should take a specific value of `k` for example.

There are also two given vectors `cos` and `ens` each having dimension 21x1. Here is the code:

```
rowsP=21;
M=0;
beta=0.9;
p=0.5;
q=0.5;
k= [1:rowsP-1];
for j=1:rowsP-k
for i=1:rowsP-k
R(i,j) = ( S1(i,end-k) - cos(j+k) ) *ens(j)-0.001*M +
    beta*(p*results{k}(i,end-j)+q*results{k}(i+1,end-j));    
results{k+1}=fliplr(R);
end
end
```

I am getting the error

> Matrix Dimensions must agree.

So I am trying to calculate a matrix results each time using two for loops `given results{1}=W (a given matrix) given k=1`.

Then flipping the matrix left to right, I get results{2} which then helps to calculate R again but for `k=2`. And this is then repeated until `k=21`.

As you see, I keep dropping the last column of each successive R, the matrix results should be appended each time giving a row of 21 elements each cell having 21x21 matrix (the given matrix `W`) and then a matrix of 20x20 and then 19x19 and so on... until a matrix of 1x1. I am unable to solve the problem as Matlab only does 1 iteration and then does not compute the correct answer. I keep getting two cells in results with a 21x21 matrix (the one given) and the next 20x20 matrix.

I tried with another for loop for `k`, but in that case, for a given `k`, starting from `k=1`, it runs the whole code for `j` and then `i`, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: k= [1:rowsP]; for jk=1:rowsP-k for ik=1:rowsP-k mh?!

Comment: One of the problems is that once `k= [1:rowsP];` gets to 21, your indices jk and ik and in Matlab you do not have an index 0...

Comment: You've set up your loop variables as `ik` and `jk` but are then using just `i` and `j` as indices in your calculations...

Comment: Ok, I cleaned up the code so that I do not end up with an index 0 and also the loop variables ik and jk are not needed I think.... this is because Matlab does fine for the first iteration for k=1, so that given results{1}, it does the operation and gets to results{2}, but then does not do for the other values of k. I keep getting the error that Matrix dimensions must agree. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, We could solve the problem. If I need further help, I will reach out again.